# Does Apache Cordova handle local ajax requests?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am planning on building a mobile app using Apache Cordova and jQuery Mobile. 
However, jQuery Mobile makes great use of ajax requests that only work correctly (e.g. display the transition) when using a web server.

Apache Cordova nicely wraps the web code into an application, which I understand usually involves simply pointing a browser at local files. Will the Ajax requests by jQuery Mobile work correctly? If not, are there any settings which I need to change in order for it to work correctly?

Comment: You can try before have question. It working with ajax local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hanh says, it perfectly work since it's just a web-view.

Comment: I'm new to mobile development, so I was thinking that a web-view was just a standard browser which cannot usually handle local file protocol ajax requests (afaik). Does Cordova do it differently?

Comment: it will handle everything.

Comment: AJAX is written in Javascript. And Javascript has been designed for browsers, to give them interactivity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#History). So a standard browser is supposed to handle JS, thus AJAX, like it's supposed to interpret HTML and CSS.